# What are the advantages of PEP or Cola? (Eclipse pairing plugins)

Tags: eclipse, synchronization, eclipse-plugin, transform, pair-programming

What are the advantages and disadvantages of PEP vs COLA as Eclipse pairing plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cola [seems to have won this race](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148603/15441) in the Open Source Category - and [Saros](http://www.saros-project.org/#Known_Issues_with_Saros) is the [up and coming competitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming#Programs_and_plug-ins_to_support_remote_pair_programming).

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand why there would be a problem with two people updating things at the same time. The way I know pair programming, one person is the driver that has the keyboard, the other just sits and watches and comments.

We do remote pair programming between Germany and Brazil with multiple pairs-of-two on a daily basis.

For voice communication we use Skype.

To share the desktop we use Skype screen sharing (works best for Mac), VNC (works best for Linux) and Microsoft SharedView (works best if two Windows machines are involved).

Getting the right combination of VNC viewers with the best refresh rate can take some time to find out. Using 8-Bit encryption improves the refresh rate a lot.

If you still have troubles with the refresh rate you can try lowering the screen resolution.

We have been working this way for about 6 years now and it works really great for us.

Comment: Your solution sounds like "the next best thing to being there!" And thanks for also adding your platform-specific list of recommended screen sharing tools. +1